# Re-direct requests to SideEffect Utility Classes

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, spring-webclient

for a spring boot application that needs to be tested below is my query.

```
@CustomLog
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my_path")
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping(path = "**", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<JsonNode> fetchData(HttpServletRequest request){
      ... some code.....which also calls external apis.....
      }
    @PostMapping(path = "**", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> createMOI(HttpServletRequest request){
          ... some code.....which also calls external apis.....
      }
    }
```

My application calls an external service which now needs to be mocked.

```
this.webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://localhost:9600/external_host_path")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
Mono<Pojo>responseMo = webClient.post().uri("/aGivenSubPath")
                       .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(requestPoJo)
                       .retrieve().bodyToMono(Pojo.class).block();
```

I am calling my controller API with MVC as part of springtest

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  MyController controller;
  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(this.controller).build();
  }
  @Test
  public void testControl() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
    .perform(post("http://localhost:9600/my_path")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content("{'someData':'[]'}"))
    .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
  .andReturn();
  }
}
```

What I am looking for is to somehow proxy or side effect

```
http://localhost:9600/external_host_path
```

and redirect all calls made for this host to a custom Utility class which provides response based on the request params to the external host programatically.

I have seen multiple examples for mockito, wireMock, mockwebserver, mockserver etc
But most of them work on a given(static path)-when(static path called)-then(give static response).
I have many calls through out the flow and I already have the logic of the utility class to generate responses for provided request arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I was not able to find a answer to redirect webserver request to sideEffect class,
For now atleast managing by Mockito's MockBean and Answer.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  MyController controller;
  @MockBean
  MyExternalServiceClient serviceClient;
  @Autowired
  MySideEffectService sideEffect;
  @Before
  public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(this.controller).build();     
    Mockito.when(serviceClient.getMethod(any(),anyBoolean())).thenAnswer((Answer) invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        Object mock = invocation.getMock();
        return sideEffect.getMethod((Map<String, List<String>>) args[0], (Boolean) args[1]);
    });
  }
  @Test
  public void testControl() throws Exception {
    mockMvc
    .perform(post("http://localhost:9600/my_path")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .content("{'someData':'[]'}"))
    .andExpect(status().isAccepted())
  .andReturn();
  }
}
```

Will still have a lookout for a way (Maybe TestContainers with image creation on the fly that will create a server with my mockCode, so that i can use hostname of this one and replace with existing real hostname)